# Django Pipeline doesn't load static files - throws a CompilerError

Tags: python, django, django-pipeline

On my local it works fine but on my production environment I can compile less files but when I want to load them like:

```
{% load pipeline %}
{% stylesheet 'styles' %}
```

I get a an error:

CompilerError at /
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

is there any way I can use a variable in settings to point to the node binary?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are using the less compiler? It actually uses `settings.PIPELINE_LESS_BINARY` to invoke the tool. Maybe it does not find the correct tool? It defaults to `/usr/bin/env lessc`.

Comment: I already use that variable to point to the lessc binary. But after that it errors that it does not find node, even though the files compile with collectstatic.